# Zabbix запрос. Запрос в C#

Tags: c#, zabbix

По регламенту ZABBIX:
HEADER> - "ZBXD\x01" (5 байт)
DATALEN> - размер данных (8 байт). число 1 отформатируется в 01/00/00/00/00/00/00/00

Мой запрос
 var req = @"HEADER>DATALEN>{
                ""request"":""active checks"",
                ""host"":""10.225.XXX.XX""
                }";

Как правильно прописать  на C# ?

Answer (score 0):

var b = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(req);

```
            byte[] header = new byte[] {
                (byte)90,
                (byte)66,
                (byte)88,
                (byte)68,
                (byte) 1,
                (byte)(b.Length & 0xFF),
                (byte)((b.Length >> 8) & 0xFF),
                (byte)((b.Length >> 16) & 0xFF),
                (byte)((b.Length >> 24) & 0xFF),
                0,0,0,0};

            byte[] packet = new byte[header.Length + b.Length];

            Array.Copy(header, 0, packet, 0, header.Length);
            Array.Copy(b, 0, packet, header.Length, b.Length);
```